# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В старых системах регулировка была не предусмотрена и, когда было жарко, люди просто открывали форточки.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном вами предложении запятая нужна. Т.к. в придаточной части отсутствует двойная часть союза.

> Ср.: Григорий, обожжённый внезапной и радостной решимостью, с трудом удержал коня ***и, когда** последняя сотня, едва не растоптав Степана, промчалась мимо, подскакал к нему (Ш.)

Запятая на стыке двух союзов  не ставится, если после первого союза следует вторая часть  двойного союза то, так, или но, наличие которой требует перестройки.

> Ноги женщины были обожжены и босы, ***и когда она говорила***,  **то** рукой подгребала тёплую пыль к воспалённым ступням, словно пробуя этим утишить боль (Сим.)
>
> См.: Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Здесь нужна еще запятая перед "и" (ССП)

Comment: Нужна. В отличие от примера с "Григорием", здесь нет общего подлежащего. Нет и объединяющего два предложения вводного слова или выражения; вдобавок, есть причинная связь между двумя суждениями.

Comment: Но может быть тогда не нужна запятая после? Просто "и когда было жарко"...

Comment: Хотя уже нашла подобное место в Розентале: Надвигалась гроза, и, когда тучи заволокли все небо, стало темно, как в сумерки. – Надвигалась гроза, и когда тучи заволокли все небо, то стало темно, как в сумерки (во втором случае после союза и, присоединяющего сложноподчиненное предложение, запятая не ставится).

Comment: Аленка, запятая НЕ СТАВИТСЯ, т.к. после первого союза следует вторая часть двойного союза то. Поэтому в предложении ''Надвигалась гроза, и когда тучи заволокли все небо, **то** стало темно, как в сумерки '' запятая после ''и'' отсутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Alenka, запятая перед "и" обязательна, поскольку она отделяет главное от придаточного, а перед "когда" потому, что вложенное придаточное можно изъять без нарушения грамматики и смысла. Правда в некоторых случаях и эту запятую можно опустить, надо еще смотреть, насколько независима оставшаяся часть не только по грамматике, но и по смыслу, но у нас-то точно она независима.

вот что касается примера из Розенталя с "когда ..., то", то боюсь делать на нем какие-то выводы. очень уж странный этот союз. Есть два составных союза "если..., то" и "когда..., тогда" а вот "когда..., то" режет слух. Не нужно там "то" в принципе.